# Subject verb agreement with and

Tags: singular-vs-plural, verb-agreement

Are the sentences below correct?

> The average temperature peaks at 25 degrees in London and 30 degrees in New York.
>
> The average temperature in both cities drops between July and September.

I’m struggling to understand why sometimes it’s acceptable to use singular when talking about two cities.

Comment: *The average temperature drops*, good. And maybe the average temperature in *each* city drops, but not one average in both.

Comment: It's fine. This is the distributional use of the NP subject "average temperature" which refers to each of both cities.

Comment: See answers on 'the distributive singular [/ distributive plural]' by Shoe [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/theyre-using-a-cell-phone-vs-theyre-using-cell-phones/302499#302499) and EA [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/theyre-using-a-cell-phone-vs-theyre-using-cell-phones/548452#548452).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself **what peaks / drops**?

In each case it's the temperature. The temperature is singular and requires a singular verb.

It is not relevant whether it peaks or drops in a dozen places as long as the subject is the temperature.

Take an example that illustrates the point.

**John gives his mother a kiss and his father a hug before he leaves.** The subject remains **John** - singular.

A much trickier example is the following, one I have heard two BBC correspondents get wrong.

**One in five students at the city university IS Scottish.**

Once again, the subject is **one**, requiring the singular verb **is**. It is **one** that is Scottish, not **five** that are. Many people would tend wrongly to say **are** Scottish, because the verb follows more closely on **students**.